# How do I get clean URLS for only 2 variables?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've seen/read questions about clean URLs with .htaccess, but for the life of me, I cannot get them to work for my specific needs. I keep getting 404 message.

Example: www.mysite.com/article.php?id=1&title=my-blog-title

I would like for url to be: www.mysite.com/article/1/my-blog-title

Here's what I have so far in my .htaccess:

```
 Options -MultiViews
#DirectorySlash on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]


# Rewrite for article.php?id=1&title=Title-Goes-Here 
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]

#Rewrite for certain files with .php extension
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^blogs$ blogs.php
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy$ privacy-policy.php
RewriteRule ^terms-of-service$ terms-of-service.php
```

Also, is this how I would link to article? `article.php?id=<?php echo $row_rsBlogs['id']; ?>&slug=<?php echo $row_rsBlogs['slug']; ?>` or `article/<?php echo $row_rsBlogs['id']; ?>/<?php echo $row_rsBlogs['slug']; ?>`

I'm using Dreamweaver, but I am comfortable hand coding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply add a leading slash before `article.php` in your rule. Have it this way: `RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)$ /article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]`. Also, this is better to change your links like your second example (even if it's possible to redirect it with a rule)

Comment: Thanks Justin! This was PERFECT!!!! Much appreciated! I'm not sure how I can give you credit for the answer. There's no vote up/down beside it. Just know that yours did the trick! Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dispatcher by telling the webserver to redirect all request to e.g. index.php..
In there a dispatch instance analizes the request and invokes certain controllers (e.g. articlesControllers)

```
class Dispatcher

{

    // dispatch request to the appropriate controllers/method

    public static function dispatch()

    {

        $url = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'), 4);

        /*
         * If we are using apache module 'mod_rewrite' - shifting that 'request_uri'-array would be a bad idea :3
         */
        //array_shift($url);

        // get controllers name

        $controller = !empty($url[0]) ? $url[0] . 'Controller' : 'indexController';

        // get method name of controllers

        $method = !empty($url[1]) ? $url[1] : 'index';

        // get argument passed in to the method

        $parameters = array();

        if (!empty($url[2])) {

            $arguments = explode('/', $url[2]);

            foreach ($arguments as $argument) {
                $keyValue = explode('=',$argument);
                $parameters[$keyValue[0]] = $keyValue[1];
            }

        }


        // create controllers instance and call the specified method

        $cont = new $controller;
        if(!method_exists($cont,$method)) {
            throw new MethodNotFoundException("requested method \"". $method . "\" not found in controller \"" . $controller . "\"");
        }
        $cont->$method($parameters);

    }

}
```

in .htaccess

---

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question Erik. I'm not sure what the dispatcher is doing. I'll have to read up on it. Does this address the entire functionality of what's in my .htaccess? Or do I need to edit specifically for the article.php? #clueless

Comment: it is some kind of alternative :)  instead of writing your "routes" (/articles/1/) into the .htaccess-file, it analizes all requests and invokes the corresponding controllers.

Comment: /articles/1 -> means "start articlesController.php AND load article "1"

Comment: Okay, I see. Again, thanks for answer. I will DEFINITELY check this code out. THANKS!