# How can I dynamically create a slug when form is submitted to database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

How can I dynamically create a slug from an input field when form is submitted to a database? I want the user to be able to type the title of the blog in the input field, and when the form is submitted, the title will be turned into a slug and submitted to one field in the database and the slug will go into another field. Thus, the blog still maintains its original title and the slug can be used as part of the url/link from the list of blogs.

A perfect example of this is how Stackoverflow does this. When you ask a question, the question is turned into a slug without me having to type the slug myself. And when you click the link, the post still has the question I asked. .

Example: [How do I get clean URLS for only 2 variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196318/how-do-i-get-clean-urls-for-only-2-variables)

Thanks in advance for any help provided

Comment: there's a lot of info about this on google... [for php](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=how+to+generate+slug+php) and [javascript](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=how+to+generate+slug+javascript)

Comment: on submit, you need to create slug with javascript. Or, you can only create slug before insert into DB, not when form is submitted

Comment: Thanks Gloomy for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to solve my issue. I was going about it the wrong way. No need to submit to dbase. Just use php to create slug when echoed. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for answering. My issue is resolved.